# What would an octopus society look like?

Tags: science-based, biology, society, science-fiction

Imagine a far future, in which humans are extinct. Instead of us, cephalopods now rule the world.
These distant ancestors to modern day octopuses are physiologically similar to todays species, but are more intelligent (human level), and more social.

Apart from that, they retain their abilities and weaknesses, including their short lifespan (~ 5 years)

These octopuses now start forming their own societies.
What do you think, they would look like?

What I have so far:

1. Communication through color changes
2. no parental behaviour -> community raises young
3. much faster reproduction -> more risktaking
4. only piercing weapons -> shells as "spears"
5. "farm" crabs for food, easily controllable, because of 2d movement, but no agriculture, so nomadic lifestyle.

Comment: Related: "Biologists Have Discovered an Underwater Octopus City And They're Calling It Octlantis" - [_sciencealert.com_](https://www.sciencealert.com/marine-biologists-discover-an-underwater-octopus-city-octlantis-jervis-bay-australia)

Comment: This sounds like a call for opinions, with no metric to pick a best answer.

Comment: Somewhat vicious, sneaky, deceptive, surprising, and (thanks to the ink) opaque. All the routine events of life --dating, buying a vehicle, working at a job--would be a complex negotiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is way too general and opinion-based, but I will take a stab at it anyway.

I will start with facts from wiki: (1) eggs require care for a long time, and (2) female dies after they hatch, and (3) male dies a few months after impregnating the female. (2) and (3) might be specific to well-studied species.

IN any case, (1) implies that females stay with eggs, while males protect and feed them. Eggs cannot be moved either, so raiding enemies nests is a good military tactic.

If (2) is true in your species, we need teachers. It could be a separate caste of females who refuse to breed, or females taking care of their own eggs.

(3) could imply that after mating, male becomes a "suicide soldier". His remaining life goals are survival of his offspring and the town that protects them. It could also imply that romantic couple refuses to breed so they can stay together :)

Comment: Standard advice: answer only well asked questions